# How to exclude a few files in an implicit makefile rule?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am building several "main" files and currently have the following implicit rule:

```
$(PROJECT_ROOT)build/%.bin: $(PROJECT_ROOT)obj/%.o $(DEPS)
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @g++ -o $@ $^
```

Now I need to have special linking instructions for some of the "main" files. I defined the exceptions as follows:

```
SPECIAL_TARGET_1 = $(PROJECT_ROOT)build/...
SPECIAL_TARGET_2 = $(PROJECT_ROOT)build/...
SPECIAL_TARGETS = $(SPECIAL_TARGET_1) $(SPECIAL_TARGET_2)
```

and tried to filter them out as follows:

```
$(filter-out $(SPECIAL_TARGETS), $(PROJECT_ROOT)build/%.bin): $(PROJECT_ROOT)obj/%.o $(DEPS)
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @g++ -o $@ $^
```

but the `filter-out` is not filtering anything.

What is the correct way of exluding a few files from an implicit rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filter-out` function is used to remove things from a list. But you do not have a list: you only have the single text string `$(PROJECT_ROOT)build/%.bin`.

If you were to add the new rule:

```
$(SPECIAL_TARGETS):
    @echo TODO I need to write some special linking instructions for $@
```

then this specific rule will override the generic pattern-matching rule.